# validar ingreso (login) c#

Tags: c#, mysql

tengo un formulario de login (usuario, clave, permiso) que tiene un combobox, el cual permite elegir que tipo de usuario inicia sesion, segun el tipo de usuario que se seleccione valida los datos desde 2 tablas diferentes, pero me da error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el codigo final del boton ingresar es el siguiente:

```
        private void btnIngresar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //RECIBMOS EL VALOR QUE VIENE DESDE EL COMBOBOX
        if (permisoCombo == "Funcionario")
        {
            DataTable datos = CapaNegocios.negocioLoginProf.ingresar(txtUsuario.Text, txtClave.Text);

            //verificamos la existencia del usuario
            if (datos.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("NO EXISTE NINGUN USUARIO CON ESOS DATOS", "Centro Medico Chilhue", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                frmPrincipal frm = new frmPrincipal();
                frm.idRegistro = datos.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                frm.rut = datos.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                frm.nombre = datos.Rows[0][2].ToString();
                frm.apePat = datos.Rows[0][3].ToString();
                frm.usuario = datos.Rows[0][5].ToString();
                frm.permiso = datos.Rows[0][7].ToString();

                frm.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
        }else if(permisoCombo == "Profesional")
        {
            DataTable datos = CapaNegocios.negocioLoginProf.ingresar(txtUsuario.Text, txtClave.Text);

            //verificamos la existencia del usuario
            if (datos.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("NO EXISTE NINGUN USUARIO CON ESOS DATOS", "Centro Medico Chilhue", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                frmPrincipal frm = new frmPrincipal();
                frm.idRegistro = datos.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                frm.rut = datos.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                frm.nombre = datos.Rows[0][2].ToString();
                frm.apePat = datos.Rows[0][3].ToString();
                frm.usuario = datos.Rows[0][5].ToString();
                frm.permiso = datos.Rows[0][7].ToString();

                frm.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }

        }


    }
```

y en el evento SelectIndexChange del combobox (para ver que tipo de usuario se slecciono) tengo:

```
            permisoCombo = Convert.ToString(this.cmbRoles.SelectedItem);
```

Saludos a todos y gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisa que en el método ingresar de la Capa de Negocio estés inicializando la variable a retornar con new DataTable() o en su defecto en la capa de Acceso a Datos, para que al menos tengas un DataTable vacío. Ya que estas haciendo referencia a un objeto nulo. Al tener tu DataTable vacío puedes utilizar tu condicional de la manera en que indicas:

```
if (datos.Rows.Count == 0)
{

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Puedes llamar el constructor del datatable cuando declares la variable, asi evitaras un nullexception. por otra parte te recomiendo no validar el mismo dato 2 o mas veces, para eso esta el switch. Ahora, tu haces una validacion segun el permiso, pero no ve que cambia entre uno y otro (o sea, ejecutan las mismas lineas de codigo). Revisa este codigo un poco mas simplificado:

```
    private void btnIngresar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable datos = new DataTable();
        //RECIBMOS EL VALOR QUE VIENE DESDE EL COMBOBOX
        switch (permisoCombo)
        {
            case "Funcionario":
                datos = CapaNegocios.negocioLoginProf.ingresar(txtUsuario.Text, txtClave.Text);
                if (datos.Rows.Count == 0)
                    MessageBox.Show("NO EXISTE NINGUN USUARIO CON ESOS DATOS", "Centro Medico Chilhue", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                else
                    SetearFormulario(datos);
                break;

            case "Profesional":
                datos = CapaNegocios.negocioLoginProf.ingresar(txtUsuario.Text, txtClave.Text);
                if (datos.Rows.Count == 0)
                    MessageBox.Show("NO EXISTE NINGUN USUARIO CON ESOS DATOS", "Centro Medico Chilhue", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                else
                    SetearFormulario(datos);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void SetearFormulario(DataTable datos)
    {
        frmPrincipal frm = new frmPrincipal();
        frm.idRegistro = datos.Rows[0][0].ToString();
        frm.rut = datos.Rows[0][1].ToString();
        frm.nombre = datos.Rows[0][2].ToString();
        frm.apePat = datos.Rows[0][3].ToString();
        frm.usuario = datos.Rows[0][5].ToString();
        frm.permiso = datos.Rows[0][7].ToString();
        frm.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

El termino this muchas veces es redundante, revisa en tu codigo a ver cuales puedes suprimir.

Espero te sirva y revisa lo del filtro por permisos.

Comment: super, implementare lo que me comentas, tiene mucha logica, gracias estimado

Comment: el nullexception se traspasa al setearFormulario

Comment: en todas, si saco una, se pasa a la otra, y asi...si no deja ninguna de esas lineas, el login lo hace bien

Comment: Que te dice el error?

Comment: Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.NullReferenceException' en CapaPresentacion.dll

Información adicional: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.... si inspecciono el objeto me lleva al datatable datos

Comment: resuelto, ahora si, cambie el procedimiento almacenado, cambie nombre de controles y ahora funciona...gracias

Answer (score 0):

Te esta diciendo que `datos` esta `null`.

Deberías consultarlo.

```
 //verificamos la existencia del usuario
        if (datos!= null)
        {
```

Es decir

```
CapaNegocios.negocioLoginProf.ingresar(
```

Te esta devolviendo un null.

Comment: hola luciano, validando de la forma que me comentas, el error se traslada a los campos del else: frm.idRegistro = datos.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                frm.rut = datos.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                frm.nombre = datos.Rows[0][2].ToString();

Comment: Los if / else siguen como están solo agregas este if por en sima de todos estos